# How event hub triggered function auth to event hub using my own registered AAD application?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I know that I can auth to event hub via MSI with below like setting:

```
EventHubConnectionSetting__fullyQualifiedNamespace = "{Event Hubs namespace uri}"
```

And define the function as this:

```
public static async Task RunAsync(
       [EventHubTrigger(
          "%EventHubName%",
           Connection = "EventHubConnectionSetting",
           ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroupName%")] EventData[] messages)
```

But how can I auth to event hub using my own registered AAD application with certificate?

Answer (score 0):

While you can [use a AAD App when developing locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob#local-development-with-identity-based-connections), this isn't supported when running on Azure.

You should instead use a [User Assigned Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-managed-identities-work-vm#user-assigned-managed-identity) if you are looking for a shared identity across services.